# Beamer: \qed at the end of align*

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, align

I finish a proof sketch on beamer slides with a formula, e.g.,

```
\begin{align*}
P\leq n^{-\alpha} 
\end{align*}
```

How can I get a qed symbol at the end of this line?

Using `\qed` as well as `\hfill\ensuremath{\square}` puts the symbol right at the end of the formula. I can't use `\qedhere`since I am not in a proof environment. What other options are there?

Edit: barbara beeton's answer pointed my in the right direction. For future reference, here is a solution:

```
\newcommand{\xqedhere}[2]{%
   \rlap{\hbox to#1{\hfil\llap{\ensuremath{#2}}}}}


\begin{align*}
P \leq n^{-\alpha} \xqed{5cm}
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some tactics for putting the qed symbol at the end of a line that's not
in a proof environment are described in a tex document linked from a question
in the [ams author faq](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=212).  (the question will
be rather far down the linked page, with a red box around it.)

the suggestions made in that document haven't been tried in beamer slides, but
i can't think of any reason they shouldn't work there.